# Rails 3: Infinite SQL query?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, infinite-loop

I changed my User model to accept_nested_attributes_for Profile, and I'm trying to create the User and Profile at the same time. I'm using Devise for authentication.

This seems to be working -- except for one giant gotcha...

Every time I create a new user it crashes the app with "Illegal Instruction", and when I check the log it looks like this...

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2011-04-18 21:01:54 -0500
  Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"‚úì", "authenticity_token"=>"Rua6PUxnE4a4TvaFcVMfmycw8Y9AFRjEsXVrqwWC2EM=", "user"=>{"email"=>"_______________________@gmail.com", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]", "profile_attributes"=>{"first_name"=>"Name", "last_name"=>"Tester"}, "student_claimed"=>"false", "school"=>"", "invite_code"=>"Texas!", "terms_of_service"=>"1"}, "commit"=>"Create Account!"}
  [1m[35mSQL (0.3ms)[0m   SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
  [1m[36mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1m SELECT name
 FROM sqlite_master
 WHERE type = 'table' AND NOT name = 'sqlite_sequence'
[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.2ms)[0m  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('_______________________@gmail.com')) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mInvitation Load (0.1ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "invitations".* FROM "invitations" WHERE "invitations"."code" = 'Texas!' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."confirmation_token" = 'duALIT6yCL5ShpMvbw79' LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mRole Load (0.3ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "roles".* FROM "roles" WHERE "roles"."name" = 'member' LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mAREL (0.3ms)[0m  UPDATE "invitations" SET "remaining_uses" = 9993, "updated_at" = '2011-04-19 02:01:54.506243' WHERE "invitations"."id" = 1
  [1m[36mAREL (0.2ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "users" ("email", "encrypted_password", "reset_password_token", "remember_token", "remember_created_at", "sign_in_count", "current_sign_in_at", "last_sign_in_at", "current_sign_in_ip", "last_sign_in_ip", "created_at", "updated_at", "plan_code", "confirmation_token", "confirmed_at", "confirmation_sent_at", "student_claimed", "student_confirmed", "school", "invitation_id") VALUES ('_______________________@gmail.com', '$2a$10$7qzC7T6b1kLiXvPSkMRkduCFClBznDWnnOu7I1ssU8blB9NMJznn2', NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, '2011-04-19 02:01:54.509656', '2011-04-19 02:01:54.509656', NULL, 'duALIT6yCL5ShpMvbw79', NULL, '2011-04-19 02:01:54.437796', 'f', 'f', '', 1)[0m
  [1m[35mSQL (0.1ms)[0m  INSERT INTO "roles_users" ("role_id", "user_id") VALUES (3, 6)
Rendered devise/mailer/confirmation_instructions.html.erb (0.9ms)

Sent mail to _________@gmail.com (1966ms)
Date: Mon, 18 Apr 2011 21:01:55 -0500
From: __________
Reply-To: ___________
To: _____________
Message-ID: <4daced1352c84_1ff5817d6b04978cd@Titan.local.mail>
Subject: Please confirm your email address
Mime-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html;
 charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

<p>Name,</p>

<p>You registered with the email address: _________@gmail.com. You can confirm your account through the link below:</p>

<p><a href="http://localhost:3000/users/confirmation?confirmation_token=duALIT6yCL5ShpMvbw79">Confirm my account</a></p>

<p>Thanks for signing up!</p>

  [1m[36mAREL (0.2ms)[0m  [1mINSERT INTO "profiles" ("first_name", "last_name", "created_at", "updated_at", "user_id", "avatar_file_name", "avatar_content_type", "avatar_file_size", "avatar_updated_at", "address1", "city", "state", "country", "zip") VALUES ('Name', 'Tester', '2011-04-19 02:01:57.266502', '2011-04-19 02:01:57.266502', 6, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL)[0m
[paperclip] Saving attachments.
  [1m[35mUser Load (0.1ms)[0m  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('_______________________@gmail.com')) AND ("users".id <> 6) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mUser Load (1.6ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 6 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mProfile Load (1.6ms)[0m  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE ("profiles".user_id = 6)
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('_______________________@gmail.com')) AND ("users".id <> 6) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 6 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE ("profiles".user_id = 6)[0m
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('_______________________@gmail.com')) AND ("users".id <> 6) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 6 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE ("profiles".user_id = 6)
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('_______________________@gmail.com')) AND ("users".id <> 6) LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 6 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE ("profiles".user_id = 6)[0m
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users"."id" FROM "users" WHERE (LOWER("users"."email") = LOWER('_______________________@gmail.com')) AND ("users".id <> 6) LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 6 LIMIT 1[0m
  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE ("profiles".user_id = 6)

  ... and so on for about 100 more lines ...

  [1m[35mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = 6 LIMIT 1
  [1m[36mCACHE (0.0ms)[0m  [1mSELECT "profiles".* FROM "profiles" WHERE ("profiles".user_id = 6)[0m
  [1m[36mSQL (0.3ms)[0m  [1m SELECT name
```

So, this wasn't happening before I started accepting nested attributes... and I'm pretty confused as to why it's happening now. Does anyone have any insight into how to debug this and fix the problem?

Thanks!

--EDIT--

User Model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # RELATIONSHIPS
  has_one :profile, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :photos
  has_many :votes
  has_many :voted_photos, :through => :votes, :source => :photo
  has_many :ratings
  has_many :rated_photos, :through => :ratings, :source => :photo
  has_many :comments
  has_and_belongs_to_many :roles
  has_many :assignments
  has_many :collections, :through => :assignments
  belongs_to :invitation

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile

  # VIRTUAL ATTRIBUTES
  attr_accessor :invite_code

  # AUTHENTICATION
  devise :database_authenticatable, :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable, :confirmable

  # SECURITY
  attr_accessible :email, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :confirmed_at, :invite_code, :student_claimed, :school, :terms_of_service, :profile_attributes

  # FILTERS
  before_create :set_role_to_member, :set_invitation
  after_save :update_recurly_account, :unless => Proc.new { Rails.env.test? }

  # VALIDATIONS
  validates_acceptance_of :terms_of_service, :message => "You must agree to the terms of service in order to create an account."
  validate :invitation_status, :on => :create
  validates_presence_of :profile
  validates_associated :profile

  # DELEGATES
  delegate  :first_name, :last_name, :full_name,
            :to => :profile,
            :allow_nil => true

  # ROLES
  def set_role_to_member
    self.roles << Role.find_by_name('member')
  end

  def has_role?( r )
    !roles.find_by_name( r ).nil?
  end

  def list_roles
    list = []
    roles.all.each do |r|
      list << r.name
    end
    list.join(', ')
  end

  # DEVISE RELATED
  # Hook up recurly account after confirmation
  def confirm!
    self.setup_recurly_account unless Rails.env.test?

    if student_claimed && validate_student_email
      self.student_confirmed = true
      self.save
    end

    super
  end

  protected
  # Don't require password on update
  def password_required?
    !persisted? || password.present? || password_confirmation.present?
  end

  public

  # RECURLY RELATED

  def setup_recurly_account
    ...
  end

  private

    def update_recurly_account
      ...
    end

    def validate_student_email
      self.email =~ /\.edu$/ ? true : false
    end

    def invitation_status
      ...
    end

    def set_invitation
      ...
    end

end
```

Profile Model

```
class Profile < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Helpers::AssetStorage

  # RELATIONSHIPS
  belongs_to :user

  stores_file_as :avatar,
                    :styles =>  { :tenth => "87x87#", :eighth => "106x106#" },
                    :filename_interpolation => "avatars/:user_id/:id_:style.:extension",
                    :default_url => '/images/no_avatar_:style.png'

  # VALIDATIONS
  validates_presence_of :first_name, :last_name

  # CALLBACKS
  after_update :save_user

  def full_name
    [first_name,last_name].join(" ")
  end

  private

    def save_user
      self.user.save!
    end

end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `save_user` callback for `Profile` model.

When doing `user.save`, it automatically save `user.profile`. Due to the callback, the `user.profile` saved, and it calls it's user to save again. And the user save, it also save his profile......

That's the loop.

So the simplest modification would be remove the after_update callback in Profile model.

If you want to save the profile only, use `profile.save`. If the user object has updates too, use `user.save` or `profile.user.save`.

Comment: Yeah, that's it. The issue is this: there are some callbacks in the User model that I want triggered whenever someone makes a change to their profile. Without the `after_update` callback in the Profile is there any other way to set it up so that if the child is saved (profile) the parent is saved as well (user) -- not just the reverse (which happens automatically)?

Comment: Why do you need to save the user while you only has updates to the profile? I mean you don't have any change on user object, why do you need to save it?

Comment: There are some third party API callbacks etc that I have hooked up to the User model, but they use some information from the User's profile. I don't want to duplicate the API hooks, nor to make those methods public, and they run automatically when the user model is saved, so its easiest to way to trigger them was to call a user save. I can work around that, I was just curious if there was another way to trigger those.

Comment: Is it possible to call `profile.user.save`? I guess this also save both the profile and the user too but without the need of callback.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. I think I'll do something like that as needed, I just need to trigger it in a way that doesn't cause the loop. Thanks for the insight!